# Live twitter stream using React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter

I want to make a Live twitter stream on my website which is built using React Js and React Semantic UI. I want to show 5 latest tweets and when user scrolls down then next 5 and so on.

I have my own custom component in place so I dont think I need to use the embed view of Twitter. I am just not getting how to retrieve tweets from twitter. I searched it a bit and I'm unable to find any latest post. I found a few posts that are 4-5 years old and are obsolete now.

SO can you tell me `how can we fetch the live tweets (ignore retweets) in a chunk of 5 (probably in JSON format) using only javascript/React Js` without any jquery or database